# Running count in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, cumulative-sum

I have an events table and a tickets (created date, person_id) table. When someone buys a ticket, a row gets created in the tickets table (Redshift)

I'm attempting to do a snapshot table so I can see how many tickets have been purchased at that stage for any day in the past.

So far I have this

```
select
    trunc(e.created),
    count(person_id) over (order by trunc(e.created) rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_signups
from event e
LEFT JOIN  person_tickets t on e.id = t.event_id
```

Problem is this giving me a row per signup, meaning I get this, instead of one row per day.

```
trunc       cumulative_signups
2016-01-15  1
2016-01-15  2
2016-01-15  3
2016-01-15  4
2016-01-16  5



trunc       cumulative_signups
2016-01-15  4
2016-01-16  5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you seem to want is aggregation with window functions:

```
select trunc(e.created), count(*) as day_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by trunc(e.created) rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_signups
from event e left join
     person_tickets t
     on e.id = t.event_id
group by  trunc(e.created)
order by trunc(e.created);
```

I don't think the `rows unbounded preceding`is needed for the `sum()`, but I left it in anyway (at one point, Redshift required the windowing clause with `order by`).

Comment: Ah yes I had tried this, but was wrapping the whole window function in the Sum as opposed to just the first part, which failed. Thanks very much.

Comment: I'd also like fill in the gaps - right now, days where no tickets are sold are missed out. Working right now with generating a date series in RS and joining that in.

Comment: @Pythonn00b . . . You should ask new questions as a question, rather than in a comment.